# Remove duplicate rows, regardless of new information -PySpark

Tags: pyspark, distinct, apache-spark-sql

Say I have a dataframe like so:

```python
ID         Media
1         imgix.com/20830dk
2         imgix.com/202398pwe
3         imgix.com/lvw0923dk
4         imgix.com/082kldcm
4         imgix.com/lks032m
4         imgix.com/903248
```

I'd like to end up with:

```python
ID         Media
1         imgix.com/20830dk
2         imgix.com/202398pwe
3         imgix.com/lvw0923dk
4         imgix.com/082kldcm
```

Even though that causes me to lose 2 links for ID = 4, I don't care. Is there a simple way to do this in python/pyspark?

Comment: I'd search for drop duplicates. Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064243

Comment: Actually [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48062907/5858851) on the above linked question will work for you. You can do `df.dropDuplicates(subset=["ID"])`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [remove duplicates from a dataframe in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064243/remove-duplicates-from-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)

Comment: I edited out the python tag because I thought you were asking about spark only, but re-reading your question it seems like you may also be asking about pandas DataFrames?

Answer (score 0):

1. Group by on col('ID')
2. Use collect_list with agg to aggregate the list
3. Call getItem(0) to extract first element from the aggregated list

   ```
   df.groupBy('ID').agg(collect_list('Media').getItem(0).alias('Media')).show()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Anton and pault are correct:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID'])
```

does indeed work