# PySpark grouping by 2 columns to get top 1 count per group

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a PySpark dataframe `mydf` and am grouping by 2 columns (`code` and `col1`) to obtain a resultant table with highest distinct count of third column (`newid`).

Eg: `mydf`

```python
code   col1   newid
100     MNO      1
100     MNO      2
230     LLL      3
245     TTE      4
230     LLL      5
230     LIO      6
100     FGH      7
```

Expected Result:

```python
code   col1   count(distinct newid)
100     MNO      2
230     LLL      2
245     TTE      1
```

Current results using the code below:

```python
mydf.groupBy("code","col1").agg(count("newid"), countDistinct("newid")\
    .orderBy(desc("countDistinct('newid')")))

code   col1   newid
100     MNO      2
230     LLL      2
245     TTE      1
100     FGH      1
230     LIO      1
```

Comment: adding drop_duplicated for your result df

Comment: @Wen dropDuplicates doesn't take any arguments in PySpark? Eventually after Order By I want to keep only the first occurence..

Comment: Like mydf.groupBy("code","col1").agg(count("newid"), countDistinct("newid").orderBy(desc("countDistinct("newid")"))).dropDuplicates('code')

Comment: I think you're asking the same thing as another [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50685522/remove-duplicate-rows-regardless-of-new-information-pyspark). The solution is the same as what Wen suggested- `mydf.groupBy(...).agg(...)...dropDuplicates(subset=["code"])`

Comment: thanks @Wen and @pault!