# How to drop duplicates memory efficiently?

Tags: python, excel, pandas

So I have a coupe of excel files totaling 1.8GB for now and is growing. All excel files have same columns and may have some overlapping rows with other files. Currently I have to read all files in memory (which is slow and soon I will not be able to because of PC RAM limitation). I am using following two methods but both are equally memory-inefficient and almost same:

1. `all_data = pd.concat(data_dict.values(), ignore_index=True)`
2. `for df in data_dict.values():  all_data=pd.concat([all_data,df]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)`

So I was thinking is there a way I do not have to read all data in memory for comparison and ideally could limit the memory usage of pandas. Speed is not a big concern for me but memory is. I want my code stay relevant as the data keeps growing. So any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered moving to DBMS? Something like PostgreSQL / SQL Server / Oracle is designed for this

Comment: ^^^^^ Excel files totaling 1.8GB is a huge red flag ^^^^

Comment: Use [Spark/Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/) that will partition your dataset for you when creating an RDD or dataframe. If you want to keep your Pandas code, use [Koalas](https://github.com/databricks/koalas), the distributed version of Pandas based on Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Python- and Excel-based approach that will run on your current machine.  (I'm assuming that purchasing additional RAM, running on the cloud  or using a database are not feasible.)

First, create a couple sample data frames for illustration.  (If necessary, you could use Excel itself to convert .xlsx files to .csv, and then read each .csv file in chunks.)

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [11, 12, 13], 'b': [14, 15, 16], 'c': [17, 18, 19]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [13, 14, 15], 'b': [16, 17, 18], 'c': [19, 20, 21]})
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]))

    a   b   c
0  11  14  17
1  12  15  18
2  13  16  19  # copy 1
0  13  16  19  # copy 2 (duplicate)
1  14  17  20
2  15  18  21
```

Now iterate over every row of every data frame.  Compute a hash value for each row.  If you've seen the hash before, then you've seen row itself before, so just continue.  If it's a new hash value, then export the row and add the hash value to your set.

```
cache = set()

for d in [df1, df2]:
    for row in d.itertuples():
        h = hash(row[1:])    # start at one to _exclude_ the index 
        if h in cache:
            continue
        print(row, h)
        cache.add(h)   

# you'll get this output, printed for illustration.
# it's easy to parse, for a variety of downstream uses
# note that the duplicate row was NOT exported

Pandas(Index=0, a=11, b=14, c=17) -8507403049323048181
Pandas(Index=1, a=12, b=15, c=18) -2181970144325339791
Pandas(Index=2, a=13, b=16, c=19) -6414432197316917400
Pandas(Index=1, a=14, b=17, c=20) -7535143174237721170
Pandas(Index=2, a=15, b=18, c=21) 4031466940829764140
```

Comment: This worked best for me. Efficient and does not require code change or switching to koalas with which I was struggling since.

Comment: I'm not sure this is entirely correct (although it seems like a good, practical approach for most cases). A typical hash function produces a result that is probably unique for each input, but not necessarily. You could therefore remove rows that aren't actually duplicate.   A more correct solution might save a pointer to n >= 1 prior rows that produces the same hash, and then compares the actual values before removal. (n > 1 above only if you've seen two different rows that produce the same hash)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a big data problem.
You'll probably have to setup a Spark cluster on your favorite cloud provider, for example something like Azure Databricks and do this there using Pyspark.

Helpful: [Removing duplicates using Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064243/remove-duplicates-from-a-dataframe-in-pyspark)